# Can Parallel.ForEach be used safely with CloudTableQuery

Tags: parallel-extensions, azure-table-storage

I have a reasonable number of records in an Azure Table that I'm attempting to do some one time data encryption on.  I thought that I could speed things up by using a `Parallel.ForEach`.  Also because there are more than 1K records and I don't want to mess around with continuation tokens myself I'm using a CloudTableQuery to get my enumerator.

My problem is that some of my records have been double encrypted and I realised that I'm not sure how thread safe the enumerator returned by `CloudTableQuery.Execute()` is.  Has anyone else out there had any experience with this combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my best efforts I've been unable to replicate my original problem.  My conclusion is therefore that it is perfectly OK to use `Parallel.ForEach` loops with `CloudTableQuery.Execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would be willing to bet the answer to Execute returning a thread-safe `IEnumerator` implementation is highly unlikely. That said, this sounds like yet another case for the [producer-consumer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

In your specific scenario I would have the original thread that called Execute read the results off sequentially and stuff them into a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). Before you start doing that though, you want to start a separate `Task` that will control the consumption of those items using `Parallel::ForEach`. Now, you will probably also want to look into using the `GetConsumingPartitioner` method of the ParallelExtensions library in order to be most efficient since the default partitioner will create more overhead than you want in this case.  You can read more about this from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx).

An added bonus of using `BlockingCollection<T>` over a raw `ConcurrentQueueu<T>` is that it offers the ability to [set bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690.aspx) which can help block the producer from adding more items to the collection than the consumers can keep up with. You will of course need to do some performance testing to find the sweet spot for your application.

Comment: Since I asked this question I have had a chance to try and recreate the scenario I was experiencing and so far I've been unable to replicate the problem (as it's been non-repeatable I haven't been able to give it much attention).  What you're suggesting would certainly make sure it wasn't a problem.  I'd like to do some more investigation to see if this extra effort is required.

Comment: Well, honestly, I'm realizing I misspoke in your particular case. Parallel::ForEach will ensure that the enumerator is only read from the initial thread in batches and then the individual items that are read will be farmed out to Tasks that are scheduled to run on potentially separate threads. So you shouldn't actually need to implement the producer-consumer pattern here yourself at all since you've already got a source that is generating items into a stream(i.e. CloudTableQuery's IEnumerable returned from execute).